# Design of HTML table with many columns

Tags: html, user-interface, html-table

Recently, I ran into trouble of a HTML table design problem.
I have a CS program and I want to rebuild it into a BS program. This is the UI screen capture.

[image]

As you see, it has too many columns. A horizontal scrollbar will appear. How can I improve the user experience?

I tried to combine several columns into one, but it brought some new problems——confusion, not good to filter and sort.

If you have an good example, please show me.

Comment: What's a CS program and a BS program?

Comment: Google can be your friend. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples

Comment: That's a simple MIS program. Database operation is its major job. The tables in database have many columns, and they are showing on the UI.

Comment: Being a design rather than programming problem, this question does not look quite on-topic at SO. Regarding the design, it really depends on what the user is expected to do with the data and how the data can be organized (e.g., divided into more manageable pieces). To some extent, it may be possible to reduce column widths; but this depends on their content, especially “worst-case” (largest content) scenarios.

Comment: One thing that sometimes helps is using short column headings, specifically for columns with short values. In your design for example I see a lot of columns with zeroes that take up a lot of space only because of it's heading.

Comment: @tomfanning sorry I didn't make it clear. CS stands for Client Server, and BS stands for Browser Server(Web application).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After long long time thinking, not perfectly, but I found some workarounds. I post my solutions here for references.

1, Allow horizontal scrollbar for too long columns.
[image]
This can be done easily by adding a DIV tag wrapping the table like this:

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table class="no-wrap">
    <!-- stuff -->
    <!-- no-wrap is a AdminLTE style which makes the text in the table do not wrap -->
    </table>
</div>
```

2,Allow the user control which columns be shown. I did this by adding a modal dialog based on Bootstrap.
[image]
In reducing the displaying column number, you will find it looks better in narrow screen.

This is not hard by writing some JavaScript code and and make it common in your project. Do remember to make good use of the **Local Storage** technology to save the user's configuration locally and restore the state next time user opening this page. In my solution, my Local Storage key is like this:

```
my-datatable-hide-col:/business/order:tb-order
```

`my-datatable-hide-col` is fixed, `/business/order` is the path, and the `tb-order` is the table's id. This Local Storage key's value is like this:

```
[0, 3, 4]
```

This means the column 0, column 3 and column 4 is going to be hidden. If the value is not exist or empty, no column will be hidden.

3,Allow the user control the column's order. It's similar to controlling columns' displaying state above.
[image]

This also can be done by writing some JavaScript code and make it common.

Comment: Any idea on how to remove scroll and still show multiple columns? I have huge data from ML models and I am already using similar solution as shown above. Is there any alternative to tables? like Data card or something with flexible column list

Answer (score 0):

Relating to a better user experience, it helps if every other row is coloured slightly differently (like iTunes used to do before iTunes 11 changed the whole damn design). This allows the user to easily distinguish between each row.

Here's an example of what I mean:
http://alistapart.com/article/zebratables

an here's how to implement it (super simple):
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css3-zebra-striping-a-table/

Also, and this is going to depend on what the client wants, but obviosusly you're going to want to remove any columns that really aren't in use. For those columns that there is only a small value (a single digit number, for example), make them as small as possible.

Hope some of this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
                        <table class="table">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        grams
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        kilograms
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Milligrams
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Ounces
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Pounds
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        Pounds+ounce
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        0
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 0 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        1
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.001
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        1000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.0353
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.002205
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 0.0353 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        2
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.002
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        2000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.0706
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.004409
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 0.0706 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        5
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.005
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        5000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.1764
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.011023
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 0.1764 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        10
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.01
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        10000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.3527
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.022046
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 0.3527 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        30
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.03
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        30000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        1.0582
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.066139
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 1.0580 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        50
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.05
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        50000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        1.7637
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.110231
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 1.7640 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        100
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.1
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        100000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        3.5274
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0.220462
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        0 lb 3.5270 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        1000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        1
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        1000000
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        35.2740
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        2.204623
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        2 lb 3.2740 oz
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0k7C.jpg)